# Database Message Queues

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, queue

I am only familiar with Sql Server and Oracle DBs having messgae queues (Sql Server = Service Broker, Oracle = AQ).  Do any of the other DBs have built in Queues?  Specifically any of the open source options? I looked at MySql and postgres and it doesn't appear that they do.

Any information would be appreciated.  Just wondered if there are any other options for DBs with built in message queues.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 0):

Looks like PostgreSQL at least has some ports where you can utilize AMQP to enable your queing processes.

Nice PDF [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/images/2/22/On_Rabbits_and_Elephants_-_pgCon_2011.pdf)

--s